how to trash WordPress comments if its not in English
On my blog, I'm facing spam comments. Russian language comments, a lot of them. Is there any way to trash those comments automatically that are not in English?
Without any plugin please.

are you asking how to trash a comment if a function says yes? Or are you asking how to write a function that returns yes if given a comment that contains Russian? Your problem can be broken down into multiple smaller questions, not that recommending a plugin can't be an answer here so you don't have to mention that

Hello Tom. I'm facing spam comments though I'm using firewall. I have not got any Russian language comments yet that are not spam. So, I have decided to ignore them. I don't like plugin solution if it can be done with some lines of code. Thanks for your time.

This question is similar to: How can I automatically delete comments that contain chinese / russian signs?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't think it's a good idea to trash a comment just because it's in Russian. I'd recommend using Akisment to prevent/stop spam comments instead of deleting them. Prevention is always better than cure.
If you still want to delete Russian (non-English) comments, add this code to the functions.php file of your (child) theme.
function wpse425768_trash_non_english_comments( $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $comment_content = $comment->comment_content;

    // Function to detect if the comment is mostly non-English
    if ( wpse425768_is_non_english( $comment_content ) ) {
        wp_trash_comment( $comment_id );
    }
}

function wpse425768_is_non_english( $text ) {
    // Count the number of Latin characters
    $latin_count = preg_match_all( '/[a-zA-Z]/', $text );

    // Count the number of non-Latin characters
    $non_latin_count = preg_match_all( '/[^\x00-\x7F]/', $text );

    // If there are more non-Latin characters than Latin characters, it's likely non-English
    return $non_latin_count > $latin_count;
}

add_action( 'comment_post', 'wpse425768_trash_non_english_comments', 20, 1 );


I wrote an article about this to help my readers: https://thoughtmight.com/tutorial/trash-foreign-language-spam/.
I've changed the action hook to pre_comment_approved
